# Can a Bayesian filter be used to create multiple outputs

Tags: bayesian

I see that Bayesian filters are use well for binary choices - (spam:not spam, male:female etc).  Is there any way for it to categorize multiple values (eg php+javascript, house+yard).
I've seen [Naive bayesian classifier - multiple decisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953217/naive-bayesian-classifier-multiple-decisions) but I want to know if multiple outputs are possible.

If not, what are other suggested approaches for categorization (with or without learning). Especially for php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the accepted answer of the question you linked to says: "It's definitely possible to have more than two classes.". In practice, one approach is to train multiple classifiers in parallel, e.g. one classifier for `php` vs. `not php` and another classifier for `javascript` vs. `not javascript`.

Other widely used [multivariate classification methods](http://www.google.com/search?q=multivariate%20classification%20methods) include

- artificial neural networks (also called multilayer perceptrons)
- (boosted) decision trees
- support vector machines

If you have a more detailed/follow up question on this, post it on http://stats.stackexchange.com .

I'm not sure what libraries for such a task are available for php but [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) is a tool to make libraries written in C/C++ usable from php.